# How to use a Wikipedia Template (i.e. in English) for an other language (i.e. Norweigian)?

Tags: templates, wikipedia

I have the following problem.
I would like to create a Template (which exists already in English) in German. For this I translated the text, changed some parameters. But, in the English Template, there are some other Templates included - but they do not exist in German, i.e. Ambox.

When I will run the Template, it allways pops up, Template:Ambox is not existing. Is it possible, to use the Ambox Template without creating a new one for German Wikipedia?

Comment: Is this question about programming at all?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know,
if there is any command, which allows the use of a template in an other language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about programming as defined in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to use a template from another wiki, you have to copy it to your wiki (and any templates and modules it depends on too).

See also [*Use of templates across wikis* on the meta-wiki](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Template#Use_of_templates_across_wikis).